# Is it possible to evaluate a "complex" xpath expression stored in a variable using xquery (BaseX)?

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

I'm trying to do something like this in xquery (working with basex)

```
let $node := doc('doc.xml')//*:root
let $xpath := "descendant::*:path/*:to/*:node"

let $val := $node//$xpath
```

It is possible with [functx:dynamic-path](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_dynamic-path.html)

```
let $val := functx:dynamic-path($node, $xpath)
```

but this one does not allow much

> The function only supports element names and attribute names preceded by @, **separated by single slashes**. The names can optionally be prefixed, but they must use the same prefix that is used in the input document. It **does not support predicates**, other axes or other node kinds. Note that most processors have an extension function that evaluates path expressions dynamically in a much more complete way.

Do you know any other function that could help ?

Comment: Look at http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module#xquery:eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module#xquery:eval:

```
let $node := doc('doc.xml')//*:root
let $xpath := "descendant::*:path/*:to/*:node"

let $val := xquery:eval($path, map { '' : $node })
```